# Error appending to <select> element in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I can not seem to append items to a `<select>` element in Internet Explorer 8. Here is the code, it works perfectly in Chrome and internet explorer 9, is there another way I should do it so that it works in Internet Explorer 8?

```
$("#" + data[0].Name).append($('<option/>', {
    value: data[i].Values[k].Value,
    text: data[i].Values[k].Label
}));
```

Comment: Are you using the latest version of jQuery ?

Comment: I am using 1.5.1, I Changed this to use this http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js one, but still the error persists.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your code.  I haven't tested jQuery 1.5.1, but you can see it [working fine in 1.5.2](http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/cCLyt/1/).  What is the error you're getting?

Comment: Microsoft JScript runtime error : Unexpected call to method or property access. I get the error in IE 7 as well.

Comment: Where is your data object defined ? Could you check its value on ie ?

Comment: data is the result of an ajax call, and in this case, it the first time it will read $("#AssetId") , as for the other values I can enter anything in them the same error comes up.

Comment: Some how my function that renders the controls on the page made the $(#AssetId) a textbox, when I fixed this the error went away. Looks like IE 9 just ignores this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the working solution.
http://jsfiddle.net/8yFsh/

It worked for me in IE8. below is the code to add option

```
$('#ptest'). 
      append($("<option></option>"). 
      attr("value","pavan"). 
      text("pavan"));
```

Comment: +1 - This is a brilliant solution @pavan - works for me in all browsers where other solutions suggesting the use of `.hide().show()` had failed